# Exchange Server 2007 Backup

Tags: exchange-2007

I want to know what is the EASIEST way to ensure I have a strong exchange backup, which is simple to manage and low in risk.
Is imaging the machine with windows server backup image enough?

Pretty amateur exchange admin here.

Answer (score 2):

Using the VSS provider / Windows Server Backup to copy Exchange 2007 database and log files is an [officially supported backup option since Service Pack of Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124515%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). 
See

- Technet Exchange documentation: [Using Windows Server Backup to Back Up and Restore Exchange Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221172%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

for further reading.

Your mileage on the topic of "simple to manage" might vary. Especially since to serve restore requests for single mailboxes the restore would need to go into a [Recovery Storage Group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997694%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) first.

There are commercial 3rd party backup solutions to do a mailbox-level or even object-level restore with nifty GUIs allowing to navigate through the backed up Exchange store - if you have no administration experience with Exchange whatsoever and are new to PowerShell or command lines in general, you might prefer the 3rd-party approach.